# How to use draft-js-plugins in react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form, draft-js-plugins

I am using react-hook-form and draft.js as wysiwiyg.
My code where I am using draft-js-plugins:

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import { Controller } from "./src";
import Editor from "@draft-js-plugins/editor";
import createToolbarPlugin from "@draft-js-plugins/static-toolbar";
import "draft-js/dist/Draft.css";
import "@draft-js-plugins/static-toolbar/lib/plugin.css";

const staticToolbarPlugin = createToolbarPlugin();
const { Toolbar } = staticToolbarPlugin;
const plugins = [staticToolbarPlugin];

function RichText({ control }) {
  const editor = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
        minHeight: 30,
        padding: 10
      }}
    >
      <Toolbar />
      <Controller
        ref={editor}
        name="DraftJS"
        control={control}
        plugins={plugins}
        render={({ value, onChange }) => {
          return <Editor editorState={value} onChange={onChange} />;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default RichText;
```

All is ok, I see plugins. But when I want select word and click to plugin (I, B, U) button show me error

```
props.getEditorState is not a function
```

I don't understand how to solve it? I found some examples https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/static-toolbar .but didn't help

live example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sfy5j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to place the `<Toolbar />` component as a sibling to your `<Editor />` component and also pass the `ref` to it.

```js
<Controller
  name="DraftJS"
  control={control}
  render={({ value, onChange, ref }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Toolbar />
        <Editor
          ref={ref}
          editorState={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          plugins={plugins}
        />
      </>
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - V6 - Controller (forked)]

Comment: Thx for the great answer it works perfectly.